# Python tests separate directory from production code: cannot get consistent imports

Tags: python, python-import

In a submodule I have a class `Parent` that uses an auxillary class `Child` located in the same module.

**Problem**: depending on whether I execute the tests or run the application, the `import` statement in the `parent.py` needs to look different.

The project structure is like this:

```
project-name/
   tests/
      __init__.py
      test.py
   project_name/
      __init__.py
      __main__.py
      submodule/
         parent.py
         child.py
```

I execute the program and the tests like this:

```bash
# go to the root directory of the project
cd project-name/
# I cannot get those two lines get to work with the same imports:
python3 -m unittest discover
python3 project_name
```

The content of the files is like this:

```py
# tests/__init__.py

# empty
```

```py
# tests/test.py
import unittest

from project_name import Parent

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self): Parent().hello()
```

```py
# project_name/__init__.py

from project_name.submodule.child import Child
from project_name.submodule.parent import Parent
```

```py
# project_name/__main__.py

from submodule.parent import Parent

parent = Parent()

parent.hello()
```

```py
# project_name/submodule/child.py

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hello(self):
        print("Hello World")
```

```py
# project_name/submodule/parent.py

# Works for __main__.py:
from submodule.child import Child
# Works for test:
#from project_name import Child

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Child()


    def hello(self):
        self.child.hello()
```

---

The solution suggested by nigh_anxiety is not sufficient: it solves this particular import where the other file is in the same folder, but imports from other packages will still not work.

For that, there's [a follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938918/how-to-get-python-imports-to-work-consistently/).

The solution to the follow-up question also solves this problem, therefore it's the better solution.

But I'm not allowed to post the solution, so I just mention it here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Python imports to work consistently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938918/how-to-get-python-imports-to-work-consistently) (sorry if the auto-generated comment for voting to mark a question as duplicate reads like sarcasm)

Comment: Yes, that one fixes all the problems with imports (including same-directory imports), while this one fixes only one particular issue (only same-directory imports).

Comment: Use `-m` when executing your module, or have a python script in your root directory that acts as the command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

Changing parent.py to the following appears to work for both running the package and the unit tests:

```
# Works for both cases
from .child import Child

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Child()


    def hello(self):
        self.child.hello()
```

As `project_name.submodule` is loaded as a package in both cases, using the direct relative import of `from .child import Child` works in all cases.

The reason for this difference in behavior is that when running `python project_name`, python runs `project_name.__main__.py` but does NOT run `project_name.__init__.py`. Then during the import of parent.py and child.py, the special variable `__package__` is set to `'submodule'`.

However, when you run the tests, `project_name.__init__.py` is run, and then within parent.py and child.py, `__package__=='project_name.submodule'`, so `from submodule.child` is not valid. It would have to be `from project_name.submodule.child`

As parent.py and child.py are in a package togther, we can use a relative import and using `from .child import Child` makes the value of `__package__` irrelevant.

For debugging these sorts of import problems I like to add the following line to the top of my files before any imports, and then I can see exactly what is running when:

```
print(f"Running {__file__}\n    {__package__=}\n    {__name__=}")
```

This got me the following output for `python project_name`:

```
$ python project_name
Running ...\project-name\project_name\__main__.py
    __package__=''
    __name__='__main__'
Running ...\project-name\project_name\submodule\parent.py
    __package__='submodule'
    __name__='submodule.parent'
Running ...\project-name\project_name\submodule\child.py
    __package__='submodule'
    __name__='submodule.child'
Hello World
```

And from running the tests:

```
$ python3 -m unittest discover
Running ...\project-name/project_name/__init__.py
    __package__='project_name'
    __name__='project_name'
Running ...\project-name/project_name/submodule/child.py
    __package__='project_name.submodule'
    __name__='project_name.submodule.child'
Running ...\project-name/project_name/submodule/parent.py
    __package__='project_name.submodule'
    __name__='project_name.submodule.parent'
Running ...\project-name/tests/__init__.py
    __package__='tests'
    __name__='tests'
Running ...\project-name/tests/test.py
    __package__='tests'
    __name__='tests.test'
Hello World
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: This answers the question as explicitly posed here, but [now the next import fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938918/how-to-get-python-imports-to-work-consistently) and those cannot be written as relative imports.