# How to get Python imports to work consistently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

The [solution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936303/) works only for the special case of importing from the same directory.

However, if I put the `Child` class into a sibling directory then that solution doesn't work. Same goes if I do not `from [something] import Child` but instead `import [something]` and then try to access `[something].child`. Neither scenario can be written as a relative import.

**Problem**: depending on whether I execute the tests or run the application, the `import` statement in the `parent.py` needs to look different.

So let me ask more generally: how can I write imports so they work independently of the scenario they are used in?

The project structure is like this:

```
project-name/
   tests/
      __init__.py
      test.py
   project_name/
      __init__.py
      __main__.py
      submodule/
         parent.py
      sibling/
         child.py
```

I execute the program and the tests like this:

```bash
# go to the root directory of the project
cd project-name/
# I cannot get those two lines get to work with the same imports:
python3 -m unittest discover
python3 project_name
```

The content of the files is like this:

```py
# tests/__init__.py

# empty
```

```py
# tests/test.py
import unittest

from project_name import Parent

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self): Parent().hello()
```

```py
# project_name/__init__.py

from project_name.sibling.child import Child
from project_name.submodule.parent import Parent
```

```py
# project_name/__main__.py

from submodule.parent import Parent

parent = Parent()

parent.hello()
```

```py
# project_name/sibling/child.py

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hello(self):
        print("Hello World")
```

```py
# project_name/submodule/parent.py

# Works for __main__.py:
from sibling.child import Child
# Works for test:
#from project_name import Child

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Child()


    def hello(self):
        self.child.hello()
```

Comment: It seems the link you have provided to _The solution to this question_ is broken - please fix that.

Comment: I had the same problem, I solved it by creating a symbolic link, and I think the best solution is that, because the code editor is also can make autocomplete.

Comment: The import in your `project_name.__init__.py file` won't work at all because `project_name.submodule.child` is no longer a valid import. It would be `project_name.sibling.child`.  Did you forget to update that in the examples here but actually change it in your testing code?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update it in the example here since I just copy & pasted it from the other question instead of copying the content from each file again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how I run it:

```
python3 -m unittest discover
python3 project_name
```

If I run it like this instead:

```
python3 -m project_name
```

Then it evaluates the imports just like `unittest` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link from `./project_name` into `./test`. And write code normally. Directory structure is this:

```
project-name/
   tests/
      __init__.py
      test.py
      project_name/ (symbolic link to .project_name)
   project_name/
      __init__.py
      __main__.py
      submodule/
         parent.py
      sibling/
         child.py
```

and import project:

```py
import project_name

# code here
```

I don't prefer importing from parent directories, its hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

**1. Use Try/Except around the import in Parent.py to try an absolute import and switch to relative or vice versa.**

```
#parent.py
try:
    from sibling import Child   # This will be used when running __main__.py
except ImportError:
    from ..sibling import Child  # This will be used during unit tests

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Child()


    def hello(self):
        self.child.hello()
```

Also, in the `/sibling` folder, you need to add an `__init__.py` as follows:

```
#/project_name/sibling/__init__.py
from .child import Child
```

You must also update `project_name.__init__.py` to reflect the change you made in the project structure when you moved `child.py`

```
#/project_name/__init__.py

from .submodule.parent import Parent
from .sibling.child import Child
```

**2. Fix your project structure, putting another level between __main__.py and the submodule & sibling folders**

With this method, change your project structure to:

```
project-name/
   tests/
      __init__.py
      test.py
      project_name/ (symbolic link to .project_name)
   project_name/
      __init__.py
      __main__.py
      subfolder/
          submodule/
             parent.py
          sibling/
             __init__.py
             child.py
```

Then modify as follows:

```
#parent.py

from ..sibling import Child

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Child()


    def hello(self):
        self.child.hello()
```

```
#/subfolder/sibling/__init__.py
from .child import Child
```

```
#project_name.__init__.py

from .subfolder.sibling.child import Child
from .subfolder.submodule.parent import Parent
```

```
#project_name.__main__.py
from subfolder.submodule.parent import Parent

parent = Parent()

parent.hello()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use **init**.py for imports:

Like this:

```py
# project_name/__init__.py

from submodule.parent import Parent
from sibling.child import Child

__all__ = ("Parent", "Child")
```

```py
# project_name/submodule/parent.py
# it's works for tests and any .py files

from project_name import Parent, Child
```

Comment: There is already a `__init__.py`. It is acknowledged only by `tests`, which import it as a module, but not by `__main__.py` (see [the solution to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936303/)).

Comment: @user66554 - You need to put another level of directory structure between `__main__.py` and your `sibling` and `submodule`  folders so that `__main__.py` can see them all as part of one package instead of two separate packages.  Then you can use a single relative import in parent.py that works for both.  See Option 2 in (my post above)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/77939425/17030540]

Answer (score -2):

Using virtual environments, Absolute and relative imports, check sys.path, check file and also folder name, also use relative path, check IDE settings and update python versions